# My shouts have reset in Skyrim and it's saying I have to unlock them again

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I've been playing Skyrim for a couple weeks now, and I have a pretty solid amount of shouts unlocked. But I went to use my Fire Breath shout, and it wasn't showing up under my favorites tab. I opened my menu, and it's saying I haven't unlocked *any* of my shouts. What happened? Is there a way I can fix it without having to unlock everything again?

Comment: Obligatory: do you have previous saves, have you tried loading them? Are you playing on console or PC?

Comment: I'm on ps4. AFTER glaring and searching, I reloaded a save from a few minutes prior and it's all good now? I don't know. IT was really disconcerting. But it seemed to figure itself out after I reloaded the save.

Comment: Random glitches... it happens, but just ignore it for now.  Save often.

Answer (score 4):

No clue what happened, but it sounds like you were able to fix this by loading a previous save.

**Bethesda Games Are Glitchy**

Bethesda games are notorious for random glitches. These can often be amusing, which is part of the charm, but they are not unexpected and can occasionally break a game.

**Make Lots of Saves**

For this reason, whenever playing a modern Fallout game or an Elder Scrolls game, it is *highly* recommended that you make multiple backup saves.

In addition to the three or four autosaves, I will regularly save before any important event, such as turning in a major quest. I'll also make a new save if I notice it's been a couple hours since my last save.

**Photo Album**

Note that the image in the save game list is whatever was on-screen at the moment. This works if you bring up the menu and press save while the game is in third-person view, including if you have the camera rotated.

Since you're making a bunch of saves, take the opportunity to make a nice picture. Then, your trail of saves serves as a photo album of your adventure.

This has the added benefit of making me look out for photo opportunities, resulting in plenty of regular saves that are fun to make.

Comment: I make extra saves for the same reason.  +1 for the Photo Album idea.